# Complete list of "unsafe" characters in HTML?

Tags: html, escaping

As a web developer, I'm familiar with escaping the characters `&`, `<`, and `>` in my interactive pages.

Is there a definitive list of characters that need to be escaped when displaying user input in HTML?

To be specific, if I have a web application that displays a string of text that was input by another user, what characters need to be escaped?

Comment: To clarify, I am not asking about form or querystring values, I'm referring to the document body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the basic characters, you might want to include `'` and `"` as well in addition to `<`, `>` ans `&`.

However note that depending on the encoding of the page you may or may not have to escape other characters, `é` for instance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Can you elaborate on why `"` is a reserved character?  I know that many developers freely use it on their page with no apparent problem, so why is that considered incorrect?

Comment: @Rice Flour Cookies " is only special in certain instances (in both HTML and XML) -- none of which are text nodes. However, including it in general *may* make the escaping process simpler as then no context (well, less) needs to be known.

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to escape anything that could be programming code which would be executed by the script reading the input. Other than that, it's really up to the individual script/app creator as to what they want to escape.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the list of HTML4 [entities](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html#h-24.4).

Comment: Encoding `&` as `&amp;` makes these irrelevant, no?

Comment: No, because the browser would render `&amp;` as `&`, so you would be left with the encoded entity on the page, not the  entity itself.

Comment: The question is about what *needs* to be escaped. Which things *need* to be escaped and why? Just because something appears in the entities does not mean it needs to be escaped. (Should discuss what the user is *allowed* to input.)